# Is there an elementary proof of Farkas Lemma that does not use convex analysis or hyperplane separation theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Is there any elementary proof of Farkas lemma which does not use convex analysis and hyperplane separation theorem?

What about special case below:

If the Matrix $A$ is invertible, then there is obviously a unique vector $x$, such that $Ax=b$, is it hard to show that either $x$ is non-negative or there is a vector $y$ such that $y^tA \geq 0$ and $y^t b<0$?

Comment: Good question! Most literature has a bad preference for brevity against algorithmicity. I remember finding such a proof but my writeup is fairly long and unreadable. On the other hand, I suspect that the proof in Schrijver's "Theory of linear and integer programming" is elementary. The idea is to perform induction on the dimension using Fourier-Motzkin elimination ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier%E2%80%93Motzkin_elimination ).

Comment: [Here](http://wimcouwenberg.wordpress.com/2010/08/24/a-short-alternative-to-gordan) is a short and self-contained proof.  Apply this result to the set $\{v_1,\ldots,v_{n+1}\} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ where $v_k$ is the $k$-th column of $A$ for $k\leq n$ and $v_{n+1}=-b$.  Not sure if this fits your requirements (it uses a convexity argument).

Comment: The auxiliary lemma that is proven there is itself some kind of a separation theorem :) If $0$ is not in the convex hull then there is a vector separating $C$ and $0$...

Comment: @WimC Does the link prove the lemma, as phrased by OP, immediately? Please see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2732541/deducing-farkas-lemma-from-its-convex-hull-formulation-full-details-inside#2732610

Answer (score 2):

For this special case, there is a very simple solution. Let $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ be the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

If $A$ is invertible then the unique soultion for $Ax=b$ is $A^{-1}b$.

If the vector $A^{-1}b$ has a negative entry then exists $e_i$ such that $e_i^tA^{-1}b<0$.

Now, since $A$ is invertible there exists $y$ such that $y^tA=e_i^t\geq 0$.

Finally, $y^tb=y^tAA^{-1}b=e_i^tA^{-1}b<0$.